# Getting "Kibana server is not ready yet" when running from docker

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-7

I'm trying to run `elasticsearch` and `kibana` via dockers, and I'm getting errors with `kibana`.

I'm using `elasticsearch` and `kibana` version 7.6.2
and `Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS`

I run `elasticsearch` with the following command:

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:9200:9200 -p 127.0.0.1:9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.2
```

And it seems that `elasticsearch` is on (I can bulk documents and get information about the index from `python` code).

I'm running `kibana` with the following commands:

```
 docker network create elastic
 docker run --net elastic -p 127.0.0.1:5601:5601 -e "ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://127.0.0.1:9200" docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.6.2
```

I see the following message in the web browser: `Kibana server is not ready yet`
And I see the following logs in the console:

```
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-05-22T06:45:20Z","tags":["info","savedobjects-service"],"pid":7,"message":"Waiting until all Elasticsearch nodes are compatible with Kibana before starting saved objects migrations..."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-05-22T06:45:20Z","tags":["error","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":7,"message":"Request error, retrying\nHEAD http://127.0.0.1:9200/.apm-agent-configuration => connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9200"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-05-22T06:45:20Z","tags":["error","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":7,"message":"Request error, retrying\nGET http://127.0.0.1:9200/_xpack => connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9200"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-05-22T06:45:20Z","tags":["error","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":7,"message":"Request error, retrying\nGET http://127.0.0.1:9200/_nodes?filter_path=nodes.*.version%2Cnodes.*.http.publish_address%2Cnodes.*.ip => connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9200"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-05-22T06:45:20Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":7,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://127.0.0.1:9200/"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-05-22T06:45:20Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":7,"message":"No living connections"}
Could not create APM Agent configuration: No Living connections
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-05-22T06:45:20Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":7,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://127.0.0.1:9200/"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-05-22T06:45:20Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":7,"message":"No living connections"}
```

How can I run kibana via docker ?

Answer (score 1):

You've created a docker network for the Kibana container, but the Elastic container is not joined to it. Since you can access Elastic from your localhost:9200, there is no need to use the elastic network for the Kibana container.

Update the Kibana docker run command to `docker run -p 127.0.0.1:5601:5601 -e "ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://host.docker.internal:9200" docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.6.2`

This removes the join to the elastic network, and updates the ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS environment variable so that it uses the localhost of the machine instead of container.

Comment: Same results: "Unable to revive connection: http://host.docker.internal:9200/"

Comment: An alternative path would be to add a name to your elastic container by adding --name es01 to your docker run cmd. Docker then assigns the name es01 to that running container. This would require updating the ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS environment variable to "http://es01:9200", when running the Kibana container.

Comment: thanks for your help    in my case need to -e       "ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://host.docker.internal:9200"

Answer (score 0):

Did you try enrolling kibana to you elasticsearch cluster?

- The enrollment token is valid for 30 minutes. If you need to generate a new enrollment token, run the elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token tool on your existing node. This tool is available in the Elasticsearch bin directory of the Docker container.

For example, run the following command on the existing es01 node to generate an enrollment token for newer nodes to be added:

> docker exec -it es01
> /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token -s
> node

- When you start Kibana, a unique link is output to your terminal.
  To access Kibana, click the generated link in your terminal.
- Then in your browser, paste the enrollment token that you copied when starting Elasticsearch and click the button to connect your Kibana instance with Elasticsearch.
- Log in to Kibana as the elastic user with the password that was generated when you started Elasticsearch.

More details [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-get-started/current/get-started-stack-docker.html#docker-start-enroll)